# How to copy a file between docker containers?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I have two different docker containers, each of them runs a PHP application. The problem that I have to solve is copy a list of files (using the PHP `copy` command) from container 1 to container 2.

Eg:

```
copy('var/www/html/uploads/test.jpg', 'var/www/html/site/uploads/test.jpg');
```

Now, the container 1 doesn't have access to container 2 which is `site`.

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Create a service endpoint on application 2, that application 1 can send the files to. REST or gRPC or something like that.

Comment: please study the command : `docker cp` and other related commands

Comment: Isn't it better to store the files outside of the docker container and let both containers access that storage?

Comment: docker cp <sourcefile> <container>:<targetlocation>

is the normal command.

You could wrap that in PHP using shell_exec("docker cp /var/www/tmp.txt container1:/var/www/");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a shared volume to transfer data. So mount

```
-v filetransfer:/var/www/html/transfer
or
--mount type=volume,source=filetransfer,destination=/var/www/html/transfer
```

to both containers. If both containers running different non-root users you have to ensure file permissions are set accordingly.
If you want to avoid file corruption use `:ro` (read-only) for all but one containers or ensure that by code.

Other comments:

- `docker cp` is used to copy files from host to container or vice versa.
- Building a REST-API for copying a single file is in my opinion a little bit over-engineered, as long as you're using the same host.

Comment: Countdown to "how do I copy files between containers that run on different hosts" :)

Comment: Due to the fact the question is about 2 containers and labeled with docker-compose I assumed it is using the same host, but you're right..